# inheriting class is not running super().__init() of inherited class

Tags: python, scrapy

When running the crawler a error is returned 
`NameError: name 'db' is not defined`

I suspect that this is because init is not executed but I'm not sure what is wrong with the code? Any idea? The super statement seems good, I even tried a few other like `super(TopAnimePipeline, self).__init__()`.

Code :

```
import pymongo
from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class MongoDBPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        connection = pymongo.MongoClient(
            settings['MONGODB_SERVER'],
            settings['MONGODB_PORT']
        )
        db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        valid = True
        for data in item:
            if not data:
                valid = False
                raise DropItem("Missing {0}!".format(data))
        if valid:
            self.collection.insert(dict(item))

        return item

class SeasonalAnimePipeline(MongoDBPipeline):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION'][0]]

class TopAnimePipeline(MongoDBPipeline):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION'][1]]
```

Comment: You need `self.db` in both the classes and super class.

Comment: I doesn't just inherit it from the previous class? Why is that?

Comment: Wow it freaking works

Comment: You're confusing instance variables with local variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code to a simplified version. This way you are able to access the *db* variable. You can take this as reference and then make your code. Kindly check the below example.

```
class MongoDBPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        connection = 'col'
        self.db = {'a': 1}

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        valid = True
        return item

class SeasonalAnimePipeline(MongoDBPipeline):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.collection = self.db

a = SeasonalAnimePipeline()
print(a.collection)
```